# Override iframe js file over parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a parent jsp file with an inline iframe. 
The parent jsp file incorporates a js file `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.12.min.js"></script>`

However I want the iframe to use jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js
I incorporated the below in my iframe jsp file `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.min.js"></script>`

But this doesn't seem to work. The iframe still loads with 1.8.12 js file.

How can I force iframe to use 1.8.17 and not 1.8.12? 
Changing the version in parent jsp is not an option.

Comment: Scripts in parent frames do not affect child frames at all.

Comment: Can you show an example of this?

Comment: If you inspect the iframe while it's contained in its parent document, you will only ever see information for the parent. You need to view the iframe page separately to determine what's being loaded/used.